# How to create a meal menu in a pop-up in Drupal Commerce?

Tags: commerce, javascript

For a take away restaurant, I would like to know if there is a way (modules) to have a pop-up that allow the customer to have more items options when he adds a product to his cart.

http://www.eatsushi.fr/shop

Comment: What do you mean? What item options are you talking about? Perhaps try https://www.drupal.org/project/ctools_automodal  This is a modal window and not a popup, but you could add anything to the form with a `hook_form_alter`. and Ctools Automodal should play nice with existing Commerce forms.

Comment: Your right, I meant modal window. I will read the documentation of this module. It may be works as I want. Thanks.